# Defining names in python

Tags: python

I am confused on why my program is not working. I am supposed to use nested ifs to ask people their name and title(doctor, female, male) and then print out either Ms. name Mr. name or Dr. name. If anyone knows the issue that I have run into, plz respond.

```
name = input("Enter your name : ")
title = input("Enter your title (doctor, female, male) : ")

female = ("Ms.")
doctor = ("Dr.")
male = ("Mr.")

if title == "doctor":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if title != "male":
        print(doctor)
else:
        print(male)
else:
    print(female)
```

Comment: How could a title be equal to "doctor" and _not_ be unequal to "male"? That's what your nested `if` is looking for; you have a logic issue to tackle

Comment: your indentation for the first else is wrong, should be indented to be aligned with the nested if. Also the logic behind the nested if-statement is wrong

Comment: I honestly don't know, that is why I posted this question. I just need some help on it

Comment: yes @CodyCodez, you have indentation issues in the above code. Try reading up on indentation in Python and simplify your code to a single working case, then expand into more use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have made some Indentation issues and you don't need to use nested if else try this:

```
name = input("Enter your name : ")
title = input("Enter your title (doctor, female, male) : ")

female = ("Ms."+name)
doctor = ("Dr."+name)
male = ("Mr."+name)

if title == "doctor":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    print(doctor)
elif title == "male":
    print(male)
else:
    print(female)
```

Comment: This will only print Dr. or Ms. Mr will never get printed

Comment: I understand this way of putting it but my teacher wants me to use nested ifs.

Comment: @Joseph if you need nested ifs, then you need to change your logic

Answer (score 2):

The logic for your if statements should be the following:

1. print Dr + name if title is doctor
2. print Mr + name if title is male
3. print Ms + name if title is female

These three statements are parallel to each other, so there shouldn't be a nested if statement in the first place. I suggest you read up on the if - elif - else statement in python

```
if title == "doctor": 
    print(doctor)
elif title == "male":
    print(male)
else:
    print(female)
```

If you want nested if-statements, then you need to change your logic. Here is one example.

1. if title is not doctor

   a) check if title is male and print male

   b) print female (since if title is not doctor or male, it has to be female. unless you are allowing invalid input)
2. else print doctor

```
if title != "doctor": 
    if title == "male":
        print(male)
    else:
        print(female)
else:
    print(doctor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You much more careful:

```
name = input("Enter your name : ")
title = input("Enter your title (doctor, female, male) : ")

female = ("Ms.")
doctor = ("Dr.")
male = ("Mr.")

if title == "doctor":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if title != "male":
        print(doctor)
    else:
        print(male)
else:
    print(female)
```

if and else should be in the same line

Comment: This will only print Ms or Dr. Mr will never get printed