# Python nested ifs

Tags: python

I am confused on how to make my program print male. I am supposed to use nested ifs to ask people their name and title(doctor, female, male) and then print out either Ms. name Mr. name or Dr. name. If anyone knows the issue that I have run into, please respond.

```
name = input("Enter your name : ")
title = input("Enter your title (doctor, female, male) : ")

female = ("Ms.")
doctor = ("Dr.")
male = ("Mr.")

if title == "doctor":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if title != "male":
        print(doctor, name)
    else:
        print(male, name)
else:
    print(female, name)
```

Comment: Well, `==` and `!=` are not the right operators to use in this context. If `title` is `"doctor"`, it can't be `"male"`.

Comment: Oh, and why did you repost your question from earlier?

Answer (score 4):

An `if` will only execute the content of its body if the condition is true. Here because the test for "male" is *inside* the test for "doctor", you already know `title` is "doctor", and so it can never be "male".

Either your check for male should be inside the `else` branch:

```py
if title == "doctor":
    print(doctor, name)
else:
    if title == "male":
        print(male, name)
    else:
        print(female, name)
```

or you should use the usual *contraction*, which in Python is called `elif`:

```py
if title == "doctor":
    print(doctor, name)
elif title == "male":
    print(male, name)
else:
    print(female, name)
```

Comment: @Joseph Why exactly did you need this [again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60513417/476)?!

Comment: Woah. Shall I flag?

Comment: What is a flag.

Comment: Also to answer @deceze, I am practicing for my test at school and just needed some help with this one question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use elif:

```
if title == "doctor":
    print(doctor, name)
elif title == "male":
    print(male, name)
else:
    print(female, name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if the `title` is `Dr` or not, and if not to check if it's `male` or `female`

```
if title == "doctor":
    print(doctor, name)
else:
    if title == "male":
        print(male, name)
    else:
        print(female, name)
```

Or using `if elif else`

```
if title == "doctor":
    print(doctor, name)
elif title == "male":
    print(male, name)
else:
    print(female, name)
```

Comment: Arguably that should be `if..elif..else`, no nested statements…

Comment: `elif` would be even better.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but my teacher wants it this way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @deceze since `Dr` is for both genders it seemed to me more intuitive, but I'll add another option.

Comment: @Joseph I added `if elif else` solution.